# How can I find words of a specific character length in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am looking to find words of 14 or more characters in Notepad++. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately notepad++ doesn't do regex multipliers so you have to do a regex search (Search -> Find -> Search Mode = 'Regular Expression') for:

```
\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w+
```

Each '\w' is a word character (not spaces or punctuation ect.) and the last '\w+' means that it should find one or more of them so the expression mean 14 or more word characters.

Comment: This works, but newer version of Notepad++ support multipliers. @Will: The *word* character (`\w`) also matches digits (`0-9`) and underscores (`_`). This might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Cool, looks like I was testing it on an earlier version. Then `\w{14,}` should work or `[A-z]{14,}` if you want to only include alphabetic letters.

Comment: Yes, `\w{14,}` will work as expected. However, be aware that `[A-z]` is **not** the same as `[A-Za-z]`, since it includes the following characters: ``[\]^_`​``

Answer (score 2):

If you use Notepad++ 6, you can take advantage of the new regex engine that supports [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) ([source](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html)).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and perform the following search:

```
Find:        [A-Za-z]{14,}
Search mode: Regular Expression
```

`[A-Za-z]` means every uppercase or lower case letter. `{14,}` means 14 times or more.

Note that `[A-Za-z]` won't work reliably for texts in some languages. To include all letter characters from the [Windows-1252 character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), use `[A-Za-zƒŠŒŽšœžŸªµºÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` instead.

For more information on regular expressions, consult [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score -1):

**hi this is my first answer here :D** 
if you consider your word composed of anything except space or new line, comma, dot or quote then use this regex

Press Ctrl + F and perform the following search:

Find:        **[^[:blank:]^\n.,']{14,}**
Search mode: Regular Expression

hope it works for u .

Comment: the one who put -1 , can you elaborate why ? maybe we could learn more from your knowledge hhh