# How Can I Find Nth Character in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

From the following text, I'd like to find a *n* th character. For example, the 10th character is "`u`"`.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ac arcu sit amet lorem mollis dignissim ac ut metus. Aliquam sed nulla ut risus sollicitudin luctus vitae eget quam. Nam velit diam, ullamcorper id tempus ac, iaculis sed arcu.

According to [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/451580/how-can-i-find-words-of-a-specific-character-length-in-notepad), `\w{10,}` would work but when I type it in the `Find what` field of the `Find`window, it produces the message, 'Can't find the text: "\w{10,}"'

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should update your N++ as that regex should work to find strings of word characters equal to or greater than a length of 10 instead of giving a "Can't find the text" message.

Comment: @Thell I'm using the portable v5.9.8. The reason is as far as I remember the recent versions of the portable build had an issue that the registered Run commands gets disappeared. I'll see if I can upgrade it. Thanks for telling me it.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Press Crtl-G and choose Offset. Enter 10.

[image]